# Issues with InheritanceType.JOINED and Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

My simple Spring Boot project contains a Payment class with two subclasses a) Cash and b) Card

The entity code for the Payment class is

```
//imports omitted    

 @Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="pay_generic")
public abstract  class Payment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedAt;

    private Double money;
    private String reason;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
```

the first subclass has the following code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="pay_cash")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class CashPayment extends Payment{

    private Long retailerId;
    private Long terminalId;
```

and the second subclass the following code/annotations

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="pay_card")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class CardPayment extends Payment {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "card_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Card card;
```

When I am sending a post request to http://localhost:8080/payments with body

```
{
    "money": 4,
    "retailerId": 4,
    "user": "/users/8"
}
```

I noticed that only the parent database table has data. Only one insert statement is found on the logs.
 The table pay_generic has data, however the sub-table pay_cash has not

Some SQL that might be helpful:

```
CREATE TABLE `pay_generic` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `money` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `payment_user_fk_idx` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `payment_user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `pay_cash` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `retailer_id` int NOT NULL,
  `terminal_id` int DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `fk1_test_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk1_test` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `pay_generic` (`id`)
)
```

So the question is why the child db table does not have any data? I created the project from spring initialz today and the db is MySQL.

Comment: Can you show the business logic where you are actually saving the entities. Also `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")` is completely unnecessary - what it does is it allows you to have a different name for the primary key in the child tables, if it's still the same ('id') then you don't need to specify it.

Comment: There is no business logic actually. Spring data rest in a sense offers the rest controllers out of the box. And I was hopping that the data of the POST body request was enough for Spring in order to understand that the Payment is CashPayment and not CardPayment

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is you are making the request to '/payments'. If it generates requests automatically it could be deciding on which entity to insert based on the url - /payments = Payment and /cash-payments = CashPayment

Comment: I am getting a 404 here http://localhost:8080/cash-payments (GET)